# Prefuse import into eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, prefuse

I'm attempting to import the Prefuse graphing project into eclipse following the readme.

The readme instructions seem fairly straight forward, import as an existing project and select archive.

Unfortunately when I select the archive in either Windows or Ubuntu, I cannot see any projects to import. I'm currently running in Ubuntu 11.10, Eclipse Indigo, and and openJDK-7.

Everywhere online it seems that noone has had a problem with this package so I'm not sure what I'm not doing right.

> you can use the Eclipse integrated development environment (available for free at http://ww.eclipse.org) to load the source files, then Eclipse will compile the software for you. Within Eclipse, right-click the background of the "Package Explorer" panel and choose "Import". Then select "Existing Projects into Workspace". In resulting dialog, click the radio button for "Select archive file" and browse for the prefuse distribution zip file. The prefuse" project should then appear in the area below. Now just click the "Finish" button to import the project and build it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your prefuse archive does not contain Eclipse project files (`.project` and `.classpath`)?

In that case, you can create a new Java project in Eclipse and unzip the prefuse 
archive into this new project in the workspace. Take care that you keep the existing directory structure (i.e., the content of the src/ directory from the archive should be in the src/ directory created by Eclipse.

Where did you download this prefuse archive?